# Quick way creating counts for keys in a table

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a pandas series of word frequencies for a certain word across multiple extracts of text e.g. 10, 5, 10, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1... and would like to produce a 2-column table where I would like the word frequency as the key and the number of times that frequency occurs against it.

Then I would like to plot this as a bar chart.

How do I do this using python/pandas in iPython?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you give a toy example of what you have and what you are looking for, I think the question is a vague at the moment (not sure what you're asking)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `pandas` you could do

```
from string import ascii_letters as letters
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy import array

from pandas import Series

n = 1000
ltrs = Series(array(list(letters))[randint(len(letters), size=n)])
ltrs.value_counts().value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

to get

[image]

The first `value_counts()` gives you the frequency of letters, the second gives you the frequency of the frequencies of letters and then plots it as a bar graph.